# Failed to execute "arc diff": not found configuration

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

Here is the logging of the execution of `arc diff`:

```
$ arc diff --trace
 ARGV  '/Users/yangyan/Meican/arcanist/bin/../scripts/arcanist.php' 'diff' '--trace'
 LOAD  Loaded "phutil" from "/Users/yangyan/Meican/libphutil/src".
 LOAD  Loaded "arcanist" from "/Users/yangyan/Meican/arcanist/src".
Config: Reading user configuration file "/Users/yangyan/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git/.arcconfig".
Working Copy: Path "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git" is part of `git` working copy "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git/.git/arc/config".
>>> [0] <conduit> user.whoami() <bytes = 117>
>>> [1] <http> https://code.meican.com/api/user.whoami
<<< [1] <http> 636,235 us
<<< [0] <conduit> 636,726 us

[2016-04-01 06:33:53] EXCEPTION: (ConduitClientException) ERR-INVALID-SESSION: Session key is not present. at [<phutil>/src/conduit/ConduitFuture.php:58]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=fcc11b3a2781), phutil(head=master, ref.master=3024f0a4908b)
  #0 ConduitFuture::didReceiveResult(array) called at [<phutil>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:58]
  #1 FutureProxy::getResult() called at [<phutil>/src/future/FutureProxy.php:35]
  #2 FutureProxy::resolve() called at [<phutil>/src/conduit/ConduitClient.php:58]
  #3 ConduitClient::callMethodSynchronous(string, array) called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistWorkflow.php:332]
  #4 ArcanistWorkflow::authenticateConduit() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:354]
```

How should I treat the following errors?

Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/Users/yangyan/Meican/go/src/code.meican.com/diffusion/DEMETER/demeter.git/.git/arc/config".

Answer (score 0):

Your error is actually `ERR-INVALID-SESSION: Session key is not present`

Have you set up a certificate yet? `arc install-certificate`